# Overwrite flags in a file python

Tags: python

I have a file in the following format:

```
[character1]    
health = 100    
lives = 3        
some other flags

[character2]    
health = 50    
lives = 1    
etc

[character3]    
missing lives line    
some other flags
```

I have information on the updated lives in such a format:
`lives[char][status]` where for `character1` it would look like `lives['character1']['lives = 3']`

So what I am trying to do is go through the file and updating the lives based on the information above, and add missing lives flags such as `character3`

```
with open('characters.txt', 'rw') as chars:
    for line in chars:
        if line.find('[') is not None:
            character = line
        if line.find('lives =') is not None:
            if line != lives[character][status]
                line = line.replace(lives[character][status])
            chars.write(line)
```

That's my general logic behind it but it looks like character is being set to the line following it instead (`health = 100`)

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: it's generally easier to write a _new_ file, copying those lines you don't want to change, than to edit one in place. Just do that, and then rename the files afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suggest that you store your character data in a dictionary and export/import them as JSON. This will save you a lot of headaches.

For example, store your characters like this:

```
data = {'character1':{'lives':3, 'health':100}, 'character2':{'lives':4, 'health':85}}
```

You can write the content to a file like this:

```
import json
with open('myfile', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data))
```

You can load your player data like this from a file:

```
import json
with open('myfile', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Now it is trivial to change the stats of a character. For example, character2's health drops to 50:

```
data['character2']['health'] = 50
```

Or character1 dies:

```
if data['character1']['health'] <= 0:        
    data['character1']['lives'] -= 1
```

When you are done with the changes, write `data` back to the file with `json.dumps`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the built-in [`ConfigParser` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html). It will deal with this directly:

```
>>> i = '''[character1]
... health = 100
... lives = 3
...
... [character2]
... health = 50
... lives = 1
...
... [character3]
... lives = 2
... '''
>>> import ConfigParser
>>> import io
>>> config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
>>> config.readfp(io.BytesIO(i))
>>> config.get('character3', 'lives')
'2'
```

To read from a file, its even simpler:

```
>>> config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.readfp(open('some-file.txt'))
>>> config.get('character3', 'lives')
```

To make changes, and write out to a file:

```
>>> config.set('character3', 'lives', '4')
>>> config.write(open('foo.txt','w'))
>>> config.readfp(open('foo.txt')) # Read the file again
>>> config.get('character3','lives') # Confirm the new value
'4'
```